# Очистить все элементы формы в контейнере с классом , jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Есть такая структура:

```
<div class="first">
    <input type="text" size="40" id="txt">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" id="rad">
    <select>
      <option>Пункт 1</option>
      <option>Пункт 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="second">
    ...
</div>
```

Как написать событие, которое бы очищало все заполненые поля. Если вручную то будет -

```
$('#txt').val(''); 
$(':input','#rad').removeAttr('checked');
...
```

и т.д.

Но что делать, если много элементов?
Можно ли как-то очистить по родительскому классу?

Comment: `$('родитель').find(':input','#rad').removeAttr('checked');` - так, что-ли?

Comment: Но ведь элементы разные у Вас. Ну, вот Вы сами пример написали, там убрать `checked`, там текст... одной командой для разных элементов вряд ли получится, я так думаю...

Comment: Много однотипных или разных элементов?

Comment: radio, text, checkbox, и option. Где-то по ~10 полей каждого элемента, по id немного я замотаюсь писать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо сбросить все заполненные поля формы, то можно обратить к этой форме:

```
$('.form')[0].reset();
```

Либо можно указать какие-то конкретные элементы:

```
$(':input','.form')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: А можно сбросить все элементы формы, кроме одного? `$('#form-search')[0].reset();`

Comment: Нельзя. Это нативный метод джаваскрипт. Но можно, например, сохранить введённое значение перед сбрасыванием, а потом его же подставить: `var text = $('textarea').val(); $('form')[0].reset(); $('textarea').val(text);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").children("input[type='radio']").removeAttr('checked');
$("div").children(".checkboxClass").removeClass('checked');
$("div").children("input[type='text']").val("");
```

Как тот так - для каждого из типов элементов свое поведение. Но так всяко быстрее чем все элементы перебирать. div - это родительский элемент.